# Embed Excel 2010 Document in Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel, interop

I've been trying to fix this problem the whole day and hope someone here has already figured out how to do this - I'm trying to display an Excel 2010 Worksheet in my Windows Form and did not expect it to be this difficult.

So... From what I've seen online, the best way to do this is via a WebBrowser control - My code for this is SUPER easy:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim strfilename = Application.StartupPath & "\SheetXX.xlsx"
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(strfilename, False)

End Sub
```

But it pops up a File Download dialog. At first, my problem was that even when I pushed the "Open" button, it opened Excel in a separate window. This I managed to fix using [this registry fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927009#letmefixit), but it still pops up the dialog before opening it in my webbrowser which my end-users will complain about.

Other solutions online mentioned the Microsoft dsoframer, but that didn't work for me at all either...

Anyone know how to make this work?? Plain and simply, I just want to see the Excel sheet in my windows form.

Thanks!!

Comment: which browser are you working with ?

Comment: ie8, but I need this to work with any user, unfortunately too - We can always assume their oldest version would be ie8...

Comment: What about iFrame, have you tried it ?

Comment: Have you tried to change the EditFlags value (not only BrowserFlags), especially the FTA_OpenIsSafe one. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762506 and http://www.deckerd26354.net/shrine/tech/tipsheets/WinShell/EDITFLAGs_Explained.htm

Comment: Thanks, Simon - Just tried it, but I STILL get the dialog showing up... :(

Comment: BrOSs - How would I incorporate the iFrame into my Windows Form app?? - Never done that before? Do you think that wuld make a difference??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that got stuck with a similar issue, the best solution I found to do what I wanted was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144756/control-excel-within-webbrowser-control). Hope it helps others too!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this **workaround** solution:

First, you have to save your Excel file as MHT format. Then, just add up a iFrame:

```
<p style="text-align:center">

    <iframe id="ExcelID" src="Reports/ExcelFile.mht?wmode=transparent" 
     width="100%" height="800" wmode="transparent" style="z-index: -1"></iframe>
</p>
```

`wmode="transparent" style="z-index: -1` is because sometimes the *menuitem* "hides" behind the iFrame's content. I don't know if you have one but you can just delete it.

Simple way:

```
 <iframe src="Reports/ExcelFile.mht" width="100%" height="800"></iframe>
```

Regards

Comment: BrOSs, I'm just a bit confused about how I owuld incorporate this into my windows forms app... What would I do with my webbrowser control? Where would I put this HTML / Code?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, this is a workaround solution for a webapplication.

On the other hand, what if you work with MHT format

 `Dim strfilename = Application.StartupPath & "\ExcelFIle.mht"`
 `WebBrowser1.Navigate(strfilename, False)`