# How to copy from Excel to Word without using the clipboard?

Tags: excel, ms-word, vsto, clipboard, copy-paste

I've written a C# application that copies cell ranges of an Excel workbook as images in a Microsoft Word document, using the Excel.Range.CopyPicture or Excel.Range.Copy methods.
But processing big Excel files can take time, and if the user uses the Clipboard in an other application during the process, my application can crash.
I'm wondering if there is a way to copy Excel cell ranges as images in a Word document without using the clipboard, to avoid this kind of issues.

Thanks for your help,
Julien

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, I have used ages ago:
Copy the data to a new worksheet and save that worksheet as a pdf, in turn, extract the picture from the pdf and than save that picture as a new file. in Word, use the addpicture method to load the file from disk...
Very clumsy, but it is reliable....

Answer (score 0):

What about copying the image to the clipboard like you're doing, but then immediately saving that image as an image in your code? That way, you can still use your old procedures and store the image internally - no longer having any dependancy on the clipboard.

I did the exact same thing in a question I asked just earlier this week - Look at my posted solution:
[Control Excel Within WebBrowser Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144756/control-excel-within-webbrowser-control)

Just use the image as needed now that you have it stored internally and set it to nothing as soon as you can to save on memory.

Hope this helps